# How to generate simple java class from WSDL?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, wsdl

I want to generate a simple java class from this WSDL url:

```
https://xyz.pqr.com/Portal/Service.svc?wsdl
```

How can I do this? I am looking for a tool which can generate the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Apache Axis.

It comes with a tool i.e. WSDL2Java converter.

using below command.

```
wsdl2java.bat -uri [URL of WSDL file] (on Windows)
```

or

```
wsdl2java.sh -uri [URL of WSDL file] on Linux
```

Through this you can generate the Stub classes from WSDL.

Comment: Can you explain further how to do so?

Comment: Sure...
do you have apache axis installed?

Comment: I am having axis2 Code generator in my eclipse

Comment: if you have configured it in eclipse then its cool...
you just need to import your wsdl file in your project.. right click on it and select WebServices option and in that click on "Generate JavaBean Skeleton" it will create Stub files for you

Comment: I downloaded wsdl from here https://qa.tritononline.com/HouseKeepingPortal/HouseKeepingService.svc?wsdl and then I copy paste .wsdl file to my eclipse project and when I right clicked and select "Generate javabeans" is says  No server can be found and WebServiceProject does not exist. Choose an existing project or use the preferences to configure a server runtime.

Comment: You have configured Tomcat in eclipse? if not then you need to

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18272/discussion-between-pratik-and-ankit-htech)

Answer (score 1):

Some examples over here might help you: [Apache CXF project](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Or just use the JDK documentation, from 1.6 on the JDK includes JAX-WS functionality as standard, including the tools to generate client stubs from WSDL using wsimport.